# Docker exec. Container is not running. Dockerize rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, ruby-on-rails-5

I never user docker before.
My final goal - to run chrome watir webdriver headlessly in Ruby on Rails app. Honestly, also new to RoR :)

I follow some manual to dockerize the simple project which is using 'watir-webdriver' and 'headless' gems.

https://www.packet.net/blog/how-to-run-your-rails-app-on-docker/

my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:latest

# Mount any shared volumes from host to container @ /share
ENV HOME /home/rails/webapp

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev

WORKDIR $HOME

# Install gems
ADD Gemfile* $HOME/
RUN bundle install

ADD . $HOME

CMD ["rails", "server", "--binding", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Steps i made:

1. Create simple `rails new watir-app` with postgresql support
2. add gems `watir-webdriver`,`headless` and their usage to one controller.
3. Generate docker image `docker build -t watir-app .` (no errors)
4. Run container `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 watir-app` (no errors)
5. the app is not available on `http://localhost:3000` so trying to connect to container to investigate:

   C:\Users\ttttt\RubymineProjects\watir-test>docker ps -a

   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
   868458c906c1        watir-app           "rails server --bindi"   14 seconds ago      Exited (1) 11 seconds ago                       adoring_volhard

   C:\Users\ttttt\RubymineProjects\watir-test>docker exec adoring_volhard echo "1"
   Error response from daemon: Container 868458c906c13928040caf4a18d6395f6b020b3eb40a1d693de84c006b9a2617 is not running

   C:\Users\ttttt\RubymineProjects\watir-test>

Ruby: 2.2.5

Rails: 5.0.0.1

Docker for Win: 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

discovered `docker logs` command, traced the problem (needed to install nodejs in container)